# Improving a query using a lot of inner joins to wp_postmeta, a key/value table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, entity-attribute-value

am working with a wordpress website that is performing the following query, but I see this query is doing many inner joins and the website takes long to load and goes down a lot, and I have been trying to create a query that produces the same result but with no success yet

I would like to know what could be a better way to do this

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta color ON wp_posts.ID = color.post_id 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta transmission ON wp_posts.ID = transmission.post_id 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta model ON wp_posts.ID = model.post_id 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta brand ON wp_posts.ID = brand.post_id 

AND color.meta_key = 'color' 
AND color.meta_value = 'red' 
AND transmission.meta_key = 'transmission' 
AND transmission.meta_value = 'auto' 
AND model.meta_key = 'model' 
AND model.meta_value = 'model' 
AND brand.meta_key = 'brand' 
AND brand.meta_value = 'brand'

AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'car'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title
```

Here's the explain output.

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys               | key      | key_len | ref                          | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | color         | ref    | post_id,meta_key            | meta_key | 768     | const                        |  629 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_posts      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type_status_date,ID | PRIMARY  | 8       | tmcdb.color.post_id          |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | brand         | ref    | post_id,meta_key            | post_id  | 8       | tmcdb.wp_posts.ID            |    4 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transmission  | ref    | post_id,meta_key            | post_id  | 8       | tmcdb.color.post_id          |    4 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | model         | ref    | post_id,meta_key            | post_id  | 8       | tmcdb.transmission.post_id   |    4 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

[Wordpress schema here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)

Comment: Can you post the explain?

Comment: Lots of joins ain't the problem. If performance is an issue, then you need to show us the EXPLAIN and proper DDLs. That said, model and brand seem to have some issues!

Comment: sure, there is the explain, depending on the number of filters that in the website the user wants to apply will be another innerjoin, making possible a total of 22 innerjoins, (most probably no result would satisfy that filter), thanks

Comment: this is the down side to the EAV anti pattern http://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/12/22/the-anti-pattern-eavil-database-design/

Comment: is `wp_postmeta` indexed on `(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)`? That would help lots. Especially if that index covers the column with the data in, that you are actually trying to select, and you limit your select list to those columns.

Comment: Why do you do `SELECT *`? Do `SELECT ColumnINeed1, ColumnINeed2 ...`. You get all columns from all joined tables this way.

Comment: Are you sure you want your `WHERE` clause selectors on meta_value, like this one? `model.meta_value = 'model' ` I don't think that's what you want, unless you only want cars for which the model name is 'model.'  Seems unlikely. Please clarify.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems you are trying to obtain a result set with one row per post of type `car`. It seems you want to display various attributes of each car in the post, and those are stashed away in `postmeta`.

Pro tip:  **Never** use `SELECT *` in software unless you absolutely know why you're doing it. Especially with queries containing lots of `JOIN` operations, `SELECT *` returns lots of pointless and redundant columns.

There's a query design trick to know for the WordPress `postmeta` table. If you want to get a particular attribute, do this:

```
 SELECT p.ID, p.post_title,
        color.meta_value AS color
   FROM wp_posts AS p
   LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS color ON p.ID = color.post_id AND 'color' = color.meta_key
  WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND /* etc etc */
```

It's super-important to understand this pattern when doing what you're trying to do. This pattern is required because `postmeta` is a peculiar type of table called a [key-value](/questions/tagged/key-value) or [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) store. What's going on here? A few things:

1. Using this pattern uou get one row for each post, with some columns from the `posts` table and a particular attribute from the `postmeta` table.
2. You are `LEFT JOIN`ing the `postmeta` table so you still get a row if the attribute is missing.
3. You are using an alias name for the `postmeta` table. Here it's `postmeta AS color`.
4. You are including the selector for `meta_key` (here it's `'color' = color.meta_key`) in the `ON` condition of the join.
5. You are using an alias in your `SELECT` clause to present the `postmeta.meta_value` item with an appropriate column name. Here it's `color.meta_value AS color`.

Once you get used to employing this pattern, you can stack it up, with a cascade of `LEFT JOIN` operations, to get lots of different attributes, like so.

```
     SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.whatever,
            color.meta_value        AS color,
            transmission.meta_value AS transmission,
            model.meta_value        AS model,
            brand.meta_value        AS brand
       FROM wp_posts

  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta  AS color 
         ON wp_posts.ID = color.post_id        AND color.meta_key='color'

  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta  AS transmission
         ON wp_posts.ID = transmission.post_id AND transmission.meta_key='transmission'

  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta  AS model
         ON wp_posts.ID = model.post_id        AND model.meta_key='model'

  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta  AS  brand
         ON wp_posts.ID = brand.post_id        AND brand.meta_key='brand'

      WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'car'
   ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title
```

I've done a bunch of indenting on this query to make it easier to see the pattern. You may prefer a different indenting style.

It's hard to know why you were having performance problems with the query in your question. It's possibly because you were getting a combinatorial explosion with all the `INNER JOIN` operations that was then filtered.  But at any rate the query you showed was probably returning no rows.

If you are still having performance trouble, try creating a compound index on `postmeta` on the `(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)` columns. If you're creating a WordPress plugin, that's probably a job to do at plugin installation time.

Comment: Followup eight years on.  I, with Rick James, have created a plugin to fix at least some of the indexing mess in wp_postmeta and similar WordPress tables. https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Answer (score 9):

This is a Wordpress database, and you might be reluctant to make extensive changes to the schema, because it could break other parts of the application or complicate upgrades in the future.

The difficulty of this query shows one of the downsides to the [entity-attribute-value](/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) design. That design is flexible in that it allows for new attributes to be created at runtime, but it makes a lot of queries against such data more complex than they would be with a conventional table.

[The schema for Wordpress has not been optimized well.](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/16/analyzing-wordpress-mysql-queries-query-analytics/) There are some naive indexing mistakes, even in the most current version 4.0.

For this particular query, the following two indexes help:

```
CREATE INDEX `bk1` ON wp_postmeta (`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`(255));

CREATE INDEX `bk2` ON wp_posts (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_title`(255));
```

The `bk1` index helps to look up exactly the right meta key *and* value.

The `bk2` index helps to avoid the filesort.

These indexes can't be covering indexes, because `post_title` and `meta_value` are `TEXT` columns, and these are too long to be fully indexed. You'd have to change them to `VARCHAR(255)`. But that risks breaking the application, if it's depending on storing longer strings in that table.

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                        | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_posts     | NULL       | ref  | bk2           | bk2  | 124     | const,const                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | color        | NULL       | ref  | bk1           | bk1  | 1542    | wp.wp_posts.ID,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transmission | NULL       | ref  | bk1           | bk1  | 1542    | wp.wp_posts.ID,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | model        | NULL       | ref  | bk1           | bk1  | 1542    | wp.wp_posts.ID,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | brand        | NULL       | ref  | bk1           | bk1  | 1542    | wp.wp_posts.ID,const,const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index           |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Actual in 2020! We have 1.5GB postmeta table and this simple indexes really get us back on speed. Thank you!

Comment: Now in 2021! After setting up the wp_postmeta index, my query has gone from 10s to 1.5s. Many thanks!

Comment: the db didnt pick it i needed to mod it to:
```CREATE INDEX `bk1` ON wp_postmeta (`post_id`,`meta_key`(191),`meta_value`(191));```

Comment: `(255)` prefix indexes don't always work after WordPress's upgrade to the utfmb4 character set. `(191)` prefixes do, or you can use the newish plugin at https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Comment: @O.Jones, The latest InnoDB row format supports larger index prefixes, and this row format is default since MySQL 5.7.

Comment: True @BillKarwin. Absolutely. But read this and weep. https://wordpress.org/about/stats/  WordPress users are more than half stuck on 5.5 and 5.6.

Answer (score 4):

Speeding up `wp_postmeta` is detailed here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

And [Why are references to wp_postmeta so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859351/why-are-references-to-wp-postmeta-so-slow)

Comment: This is the correct [link](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta)

Comment: @ahinze - Thanks.  (Not the first time I have done that.)

Comment: A plugin to add the indexes:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Answer (score 3):

To resolve performance issue with 10+ joins SQL queries on innodb tables using utf8 charset, create a new index on postmeta :

Backup database first. Reduce `[wp_]postmeta.meta_key` length to 191 to avoid "*Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes*" error.

`ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta MODIFY meta_key VARCHAR(191);`

Create index

`CREATE INDEX wpm_ix ON wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key);`

Answer (score 1):

For performance try:

Be explicit on the columns you want to pull.
See what indexes you may or may not need.
Limit the amount of rows being pulled.

Answer (score 1):

is this better?

```
SELECT
            P.*,
            C.`meta_value` color,
            T.`meta_value` transmission,
            M.`meta_value` model,
            B.`meta_value` brand
    FROM
            `wp_posts` P
        JOIN
            `wp_postmeta` C
                ON P.`ID` = C.`post_id` AND C.`meta_key` = 'color'
        JOIN
            `wp_postmeta` T
                ON P.`ID` = T.`post_id` AND T.`meta_key` = 'transmission'
        JOIN
            `wp_postmeta` M
                ON P.`ID` = M.`post_id` AND M.`meta_key` = 'model'
        JOIN
            `wp_postmeta` B
                ON P.`ID` = B.`post_id` AND B.`meta_key` = 'brand'
    WHERE
            C.`meta_value` = 'red'
        AND
            T.`meta_value` = 'auto'
        AND
            M.`meta_value` = 'model'
        AND
            B.`meta_value` = 'brand'
        AND
            P.`post_status` = 'publish'
        AND
            P.`post_type` = 'car'
    ORDER BY
            P.`post_title`
```

If its still slow, which it probably will be, try adding this index,

```
CREATE INDEX `IX-wp_postmeta-post_id-meta_key-meta_value`
    ON `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`);
```

You could also try adding this index to `wp_post`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `IX-wp_post-post_status-post_type-post_title-ID`
    ON `wp_post` (`post_stauts`, `post_type`, `post_title`, `ID`);
```

The more you can limit the select list, (the bit between `SELECT` and `FROM`,) the better. There is no point returning lots of data you won't use. You'll get the best performance if the whole select list is "covered" by an index.

Comment: Careful! creating your UNIQUE index on postmeta introduces a constraint that WordPress doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can actually change the code that handles the results, I would make it a much simpler query and use the code to filter the results.

```
SELECT [wp_posts fields you care about], wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'car'
   AND wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('color', 'transmission', 'model', 'brand')
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value;
```

Or, you could do something like...

```
SELECT [wp_posts fields desired], COUNT(*) AS matchCount
FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'car'
    AND ((meta_key = 'color' AND meta_value = 'red')
        OR (meta_key = 'transmission' AND meta_value = 'auto')
        OR [etc...]
        )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
HAVING matchCount = [number of key-value pairs you're checking]
;
```

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress there's a good query tool the WP_Query. To search in post meta values you can use this code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'fieldname',
                'value'   => 'fieldvalue',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $custom = get_post_custom();

            print_r($post);
            print_r($custom);
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

For more information about the query API, visit this site, there're numerous example:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query